# what is the value of the contour integral oriented counterclockwise?

Tags: complex-analysis

what is the value  of the contour integral oriented  counterclockwise

$\displaystyle\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^{10}}dz$ ??

my attempts : Applying Cauchy's Integral formula, you have that $\displaystyle\oint_{C_i}\dfrac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\,dz = \dfrac{2\pi i f(a)}{n!}$ if $a$ lies in the interior of the curve $C_i$, and $0$ otherwise.

here  i got

$\displaystyle\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^{10}}dz = \dfrac{2\pi i f(0)}{9!}=\dfrac{2\pi i }{9!}   where,   e^0 =1$

is  my answer  is correct or not pliz verified its

Comment: What do you think might possibly be wrong in your work?

Comment: im  confused  about clockwise  and anti clockwise..may be  sign changes

Comment: @stupid Okay, can you explain which part you are confused about for clockwise and counterclockwise? The most obvious thing I can spot is that your formula is wrong. I think it should be$$\frac {n!}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\mathrm C}dz\,\frac {f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}=f^{(n)}(a)$$

Comment: okks,@FrankW.,,,thanks  i got its

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cauchy's integral formula actually states
$$\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\,dz=2\pi i\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$$
when the contour $C$ winds round the point $a$ once in the anticlockwise
direction. Fortunately you are dealing with $f(z)=e^z$ which is
its own derivative, and so fortuitously you have the correct answer.

Another approach is to write
$$\frac{f(z)}{z^{10}}=\frac1{z^{10}}+\frac1{z^9}+\cdots
+\frac1{9!z}+\frac1{10!}+\cdots$$
and observe that
$$\frac{f(z)}{z^{10}}-\frac1{9!z}$$
has an antiderivative, and so this integrates to zero on the closed contour $C$.